# Save Spark dataframe to HDFS partitioned by date

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs

I need to write the data from Spark dataframe into HDFS in Avro format. The challenge is that the data should be saved by each day so the directories would look like this: tablename/2019-08-12, tablename/2019-08-13 and so on.
I have only a field of timestamp from which I need to extract date for creating directories names.
I have built an approach which has 2 problems:
1) There are difficulties with a date extraction from the timestamp
3) On large dataset (and it's going to be larger later) performance will be very bad as a lot of tasks are launched.
So how can I change/improve this approach?

Here is the code I used (dataDF is an input data):

```
val uniqueDates = dataDF.select("update_database_time").distinct.
collect.map(elem => elem.getTimestamp(0).getDate)

    uniqueDates.map(date => {
      val resultDF = dataDF.where(to_date(dataDF.col("update_database_time")) <=> date)
      val pathToSave = s"${dataDir}/${tableNameValue}/${date}"
      dataDF.write
            .format("avro")
            .option("avroSchema", SchemaRegistry.getSchema(
                   schemaRegistryConfig.url,
                   schemaRegistryConfig.dataSchemaSubject,
                   schemaRegistryConfig.dataSchemaVersion))
            .save(s"${hdfsURL}${pathToSave}")
      resultDF
    })
      .reduce(_.union(_))
```

Comment: You can create a new Hive table which will be stored as an Avro and partitioned by date. 
Then, you can just write the data into Hive and read it right from files (the files will be stored in the way you describe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can live with directory structure like

```
tablename/date=2019-08-12
tablename/date=2019-08-13
```

instead, then `DataFrameWriter.partitionBy` does the trick. For example

```
val df =
  Seq((Timestamp.valueOf("2019-06-01 12:00:00"), 1),
      (Timestamp.valueOf("2019-06-01 12:00:01"), 2),
      (Timestamp.valueOf("2019-06-02 12:00:00"), 3)).toDF("time", "foo")

df.withColumn("date", to_date($"time"))
  .write
  .partitionBy("date")
  .format("avro")
  .save("/tmp/foo")
```

yields the following structure

```
find /tmp/foo
/tmp/foo
/tmp/foo/._SUCCESS.crc
/tmp/foo/date=2019-06-01
/tmp/foo/date=2019-06-01/.part-00000-2a7a63f2-7038-4aec-8f76-87077f91a415.c000.avro.crc
/tmp/foo/date=2019-06-01/part-00000-2a7a63f2-7038-4aec-8f76-87077f91a415.c000.avro
/tmp/foo/date=2019-06-01/.part-00001-2a7a63f2-7038-4aec-8f76-87077f91a415.c000.avro.crc
/tmp/foo/date=2019-06-01/part-00001-2a7a63f2-7038-4aec-8f76-87077f91a415.c000.avro
/tmp/foo/_SUCCESS
/tmp/foo/date=2019-06-02
/tmp/foo/date=2019-06-02/part-00002-2a7a63f2-7038-4aec-8f76-87077f91a415.c000.avro
/tmp/foo/date=2019-06-02/.part-00002-2a7a63f2-7038-4aec-8f76-87077f91a415.c000.avro.crc
```

Comment: Thanks for an Idea! I tried to solve this problem with partitionBy as well, but the update_database_time  column disappeared in the final result as I didn't define with column clause.  The only question is how can I rename final directories so there would be a date without a partitionColumn name?
Expected result: /tmp/foo/2019-06-02

Comment: The only way I know is to override the default filesystem implementation so I'd consider just adapting to having `date=` in file names if possible